# Get next string in array of string in python

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
lines = []
with open('myfile.txt') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()

line_iter = iter(lines)
for line in line_iter:
    pos = line.find("/")
    if pos == 6:
        str = line[0:5]
        str = str.strip()
        match str:
            case "CASE1":
                editedLines.append(line)
            case "CASE2":
                editedLines.append(line)
            case "CASE3":
                editedLines.append(line)
```

in CASE3 I want to add the next lines until I see the CASE3_END
How can I get the next line in lines array (in other words skipping a couple of lines from the main for loop)

Comment: If case 3 set a boolean variable like `waiting_case3_end = True`, and add a condition in the loop `if waiting_case3_end` , then add the line without any other checks. But if you meet `CASE3_END` you set `waiting_case3_end = False` to prevent next adding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to convert the for loop to a while loop and manually  iterate through the lines:

```
line_num = 0
while line_num < len(lines):
    line = lines[line_num]
    pos = line.find("/")
    if pos == 6:
        str_ = line[0:5]
        str_ = str_.strip()
        match str_:
            case "CASE1":
                editedLines.append(line)
            case "CASE2":
                editedLines.append(line)
            case "CASE3":
                while line_num < len(lines) and line != "CASE3_END":
                    editedLines.append(line)
                    line_num += 1
                    line = lines[line_num]
    line_num += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pop more lines out of the iterator with `next(line_iter)`, it will raise a `StopIteration` exception if you try to get more after it's "empty".

For example this works:

```
lines = [ 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 ]
line_iter = iter(lines)
for line in line_iter:
    print(line, next(line_iter))
```

will print out:

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
```

So you can see it's possible to "pump out" items from the iterator in the middle of the loop.